# How can I Fetch data from database from different tables at the same time PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables that are related to one another. The first table is a product table which includes (Product_id,product_title and product_price) and the other one is images table which includes (image_id, image_product_title(FK) and image_name). So here I am trying to fetch all products with its images so it will have a product and then inside that product multiple images of a product but I am having trouble calling 2 different queries in a nested way. Here is my code so you can understand what I am trying to do...

```
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT product_id,product_title,product_price FROM products");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$product_id,$product_title,$product_price);
        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
            
  //HTML PART
            $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT image_id,image_product_title,image_name FROM images WHERE image_product_title = '$product_title'");
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2,$image_id,$image_product_title,$image_name);
                while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2)){
                echo $image_name;
                } 
  
    //HTML PART
  
            echo $product_id; 
            echo $product_title;
            echo $product_price;
  

//HTML PART
        }
```

Is there any way to do something like this ? The main idea is to loop all products and inside that loop second loop will loop actual products images but product is not at the same table with images so I am struggling to take datas from both tables in the nested way

Comment: What does it have to do with phpMyAdmin? Please remove that tag

Comment: Don't mix PHP and HTML. This makes for extremely unreadable and buggy code

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Presumably there is some relationship between these two tables, but you are not putting any qualifiers on the second query so you're just going to get every record every time. You should be doing this with a single query using `JOIN`, and yes you should be using PDO instead of mysqli.

Comment: I'm unhappy with your choice of the foreign key. It would be better to use a field called `product_id` as a foreign key in the images table. Why? It's probably a simple integer. It's more likely to be really unique. It allows you to give the image another title. Suppose your product is a mobile phone, the title could be "Samsung S22 Pro", but the images could have titles like "Samsung S22 Pro wireless ear-buts that come in the box" and "Power adapter" (if you're lucky).

Comment: Why did you just add SQL injection. You already use prepared statements so you can bind arguments instead

Comment: Its actually connected with product_title=image_product_title and also its PK is not ID because when I am adding the product there is no any ID there so when I add product in db, ID automatically increments 1 , I mean I can check last product id and add to the images id pk by incrementing it +1 but I am doing this just for hobby and I am stuck on this one

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix PHP and HTML. First prepare the data in PHP and then only display it in HTML.

Generally, this kind of thing would be much simpler to do with PDO. If it's not too late consider switching to PDO.

To solve the problem you have to use buffered results or fetch everything into an array/object before executing the next statement. If you must use mysqli then something like this should do the job:

```
// preparation of a nested array structure with products and their images

$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT product_id,product_title,product_price FROM products');
$stmt->execute();
$products = [];
foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row) {
    $products[$row['product_id']] = $row;
}

$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT image_id,image_product_title,image_name FROM images');
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $image) {
    $products[$image['product_id']][] = $image;
}
```

Then outputting this in HTML is a piece of cake:

```
<?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
    <?=htmlspecialchars($product['product_title']) ?>
    <?php foreach($products['images'] as $image): ?>
        <?=htmlspecialchars($image['image_name']) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dharman, I forgot to add relation between product_title and image_product_title. So do I have to specify another array for that to take all image_names of actual product and then to display it ?

Comment: @ErolRamacik I just assumed you have `product_id` in both tables. Whichever is your foreign key use that to connect them together.